# How to enumerate specific rows of a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to know how to enumerate specific rows, in this case only the ones after the lines with the brackets

Original file: `file.txt`

```
TITLE: hello world 
SUBTITLE: document about hello world    

[CONTENT 1]   
That's a line   
Another one   
Row    

[EXAMPLE]    
Example line   

[CONTENT 2]   
A  
B   
C   

Text, text, text....
```

Result wanted: `file.txt`

```
TITLE: hello world 
SUBTITLE: document about hello world    

[CONTENT 1]   
1 That's a line   
2 Another one   
3 Row    

[EXAMPLE]    
5 Example line   

[CONTENT 2]   
6 A  
7 B   
8 C   

Text, text, text....
```

Comment: I've choosed the Perl way because `time` shows that it's faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/^/++$a.$"/e if /^\[/ ... /^$/ and /^(?!\[)./' file.txt
```

---

## Results

```
TITLE: hello world
SUBTITLE: document about hello world

[CONTENT 1]
1 That's a line
2 Another one
3 Row

[EXAMPLE]
4 Example line

[CONTENT 2]
5 A
6 B
7 C

Text, text, text....
```

---

## Explanation

- `-p` option processes file line-by-line + autoprint is enabled.
- `s/^/.../e` will prepend the counter and a space (`$"` = list separator = space by default)
- `/e` modifier of the substitute command will treat the RHS as Perl code to be evaluated and the result placed as the result of the substitution.
- The substitution only happens when the following regex is selected:

  - `/^\[/ .. /^$/` => this selects a range of lines starting from a line that begins with an opening square bracket and range ends when an empty line is found.
  - The range is further refined by selecting a line that rejects the range boundaries, i.e., matching a line that has at least one character and the line does not begin with an opening square bracket. So only when these two are met, does the substitution happen, OTW the lines are let go as is.
- The autoprint option will print the line finally.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/^\[.+\]/{ f=1 }f && $0~/^\w/{ $0=++c FS $0 }!NF{ f=0 }1' file
```

- `/^\[.+\]/{ f=1 }` - matching a line with brackets and marking it with `f` flag
- `f && $0~/^\w/{ $0=++c FS $0 }` - add counter value for the lines after line "with brackets"
- `!NF{ f=0 }` - ignoring empty lines and the following ones (`f=0` - resetting flag implying counter action)

---

The output:

```
TITLE: hello world 
SUBTITLE: document about hello world    

[CONTENT 1]   
1 That's a line   
2 Another one   
3 Row    

[EXAMPLE]    
4 Example line   

[CONTENT 2]   
5 A  
6 B   
7 C   

Text, text, text....
```